# "Where am I?" button on the new users page

Tags: feature-request, users-page

The link would take you to which ever page you're on, on [user rankings page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users).

I know it's just a vanity link, but I also know everyone will use it (except those who are on the first page anyway).

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: Or something similar to the way that the current user is put at the top of the list on the [SE League](http://stackexchange.com/leagues) pages. But with no ranking number this is probably less relevant?

Comment: @Tshepang: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36530/would-it-be-nice-to-have-a-history-graph-of-your-overall-position-in-the-reputati, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78483/where-am-i-amongst-all-so-users, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68897/a-percentage-of-users-which-are-with-rank-lower-than-yours, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1738/user-ranking-on-stack-overflow

Comment: @DMA57361: I though of that, but yes, if it doesn't show you your own rank... And I did a double take the first few times I went on the SE league pages: "What am I doing above Jon Skeet?!" :)